# TFS 2010 Work Item -- How can I default Plain Text field to current user?

Tags: customization, default, plaintext, tfs-workitem

I have added a field *Reported By* to the **CMMI Template Bug** work item in TFS 2010.  I would like to default this field to the current user (The one creating the bug).  This is a plain text field because in some cases I want this field to be the name of someone from the field who called in with a bug report.  The person calling from the field will not be a TFS user and thus not on the pre-defined user list.  If I define *Reported By* like the already defined *System.AssignedTo* field as a FieldControl I can't enter arbitrary text (The name of the field bug reporter).  I've tried setting the *ReportedBy* field default to CurrentUser and I get an import error that the field types do not match.  Is there a way to have the current user entered by default into the field as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field is defined as

```
<FieldDefinition refname="Company.ReportedBy" name="Reported By" type="String" />
```

You can then customize the transition in the workflow by using a copy

```
<FieldReference refname="Company.ReportedBy">
  <COPY from="currentuser" />
</FieldReference>
```

As long as valid user isn't specified in the field reference you can edit the field as necessary but it will start as the current user.